# Can't search myself in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, directory

I created a company directory list in Excel and imported it to SharePoint Online. I can search other people on the list but when I go to search myself all the entries come up. There is another employee with the same first name as me that I can only search by last name. I think that since I created the list somehow all the entries are tied to me somehow and this is why when searching my first or last name all the entries show up in the search results. I am not sure why this is happening or how to fix it. Can someone help?

Comment: You're on all the results because you're the author for every entry. I don't have a good workaround for this.